# Write to a file without external JS libraries (pure Javascript) in a browser ?

Tags: javascript, file, browser, filesystems, client-side

Is it possible to write a string to a file (create the file if it doesn't exist) 
without any external Javascript libraries , purely with Javascript code ?

I'm trying to implement a client side code that whenever it reaches a page (.ASPX) 
it writes few strings into a file (let's say `output.txt`) and that's it .

From everything I see over the internet , JavaScript is not allowed to write anything to the hard drive .

Is that so ? no workarounds ?

Comment: It is not. Even with libraries. If it was possible, what would prevent stackoverflow.com from writing an executable with virus to your autoload?

Comment: You can save information to localstorage, if you just want to persist data to the client https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Aren't all external JS libraries just pure Javascript anyway? So if a library can do it, you can definitely do it in pure js as well (by copying the code behind the library's fancy abstractions). And if pure js can't do it, no library in the world can do it either.

Comment: @andrrs you're like someone who tells kids that Santa Claus does not exist - that libraries don't have some special pixie dust that makes them exceptional :-)

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, what you sound to try to achieve is intentionally very restricted for obvious security reasons of the visitor's machine.

Now "workarounds" could exist, depending on the actual objective you are trying to achieve (but which you did not mention).

- Cookies to store simple data (like your strings) in the visitor's computer (so strictly speaking, it does the job you ask for, but you have no control on which text file is used).
- Use a browser extension, which would have the permission to write on the visitor's filesystem. Applicable if you can get visitors to install such extension (e.g. if you are IT and can request employees installing specific software).
- localStorage as proposed in IanKenney's comment, if you just want some persistent data.