# Creating File/Folder with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, opera, mozilla

I want to know more about FileSystem in Google Chrome, Mozilla or Opera
. I have used `FSO.js` but it didnt help me to create, delete or list local files.

Is there any way of FileSystem with pure JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. There was a brief attempt to create a sandboxed file area via the [Filesystem API](https://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/), but it was abandoned.

Right now, the only real file access you have in browser-hosted JavaScript code is via the [File API](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/), which is much more limited (though still really useful). It lets you read files the user explicitly gives you permission to read via an `input type="file"` or [drag-and-drop](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#dnd) event.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know with Pure JavaScript It is not possible, Even with its libraries. 
& question is possible duplicate of [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707268/write-to-a-file-without-external-js-libraries-pure-javascript-in-a-browser) and there is nice comment by @zerkms

> If it was possible, what would prevent stackoverflow.com from writing
>   an executable with virus to your autoload?

If you wish to write JavaScript programs that can create files on the users local file system you're going to need to write a client side app, such as a [chrome app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index) or write your program using [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/)

However, if what you want is a cross browser solution to create files at specific locations on a user file system, it's just not really natively possible.

You may:

- use [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) if you just want to persist data to the client.
- use [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org), Using this you will be able to require the [File System core module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) and just create it using javascript as well. [P.S. Do some research on this]

Hope this helps.